# how to open sqlite database from console for iphone programing on mac?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am new to using sqlite in iphone,

I have an sqlite file saved with .sql extension, now I need to open it through console inorder to check what are the tables included in it and the corresponding data to further progress of my work, please any one tell me to do it..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the terminal or a console, it doesn't matter what the file is called.   Simply pass the filename (and path) to whatever command you need to read the file.

I.e. if I had a sqlite database called `beezelbubeats.eyes`, I could type `sqlite3 beezelbubeats.eyes` at the command line and be dropped into a sqlite shell connected to said file.